# Parent and child repositories in nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

We use sonatype nexus. We want to have common repository that will hold all the artifacts in our organization and the child repositories for each project in organization. The goal we want to achieve is to have all artifacts physically located in common repository and some(I dont know how to correct call it in terms of nexus) links from project repositories to common repositories, so the project repositories will not have physically located artifacts just links to them. 
Why we need this? Just to separate artifacts as per project using, but not have cloned artifacts in each project repos.

I've analysed proxy, virtual types of repos and went through nexus documentation. Is this actually doable in nexus?

Comment: There does not exist a concept of parent/child repositories...Furthermore why do you have groupId/artifactId/version in your artifacts which separate the things from each other...why a repository per project?

Answer (score 1):

As this post explained, there really only two ways to design your repositories layout: one per project/team or single repo for the entire organization but partitioning by the group id: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465778-What-approach-should-I-use-to-restrict-access-to-artifacts-in-Nexus-

1. Use one repo per project, then group them, so they all can be referenced from one single group URL. Access control can be done at per repo level so only this project can upload to this repo.
2. Use one single repo for the entire organization but partitioned by the group id, e.g. it will look like this, org.yourcompany.projectname.artifactid. Then you can define the repository target *.projectname.* to access control to this partition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want a Group, not a repository. A repo represents a single root directory on a disk or is a proxy of a single repo elsewhere accessible by http/s. These things are not nestable.

However, groups hold many repositories. You could create a group for each project team, containing only the repos they need, each of which could be separated by whatever criteria you want.

For example, you could have a repo that holds java DAO libs for sql databases, and another repo that holds java DAO libs for no-sql databases, yet another that contains SOAP apis, and another that holds REST apis. You could then create two groups -- say, 'modern' and 'old-school' and assign the appropriate repos to each. You could give access to the 'old-school' group to your 'serious' java devs, and 'modern' to your android script-kiddies.

I'm not suggesting that this is a particularly good breakdown -- it's just an example.

At one place where I worked we had internationally separated teams, and each had access to their own libs and central, so we had a group per country. In another place we had mobile dev and server dev, each requiring their own groups.